# how to generate bank account token from the plaid sandbox

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments, plaid

**   facing issue with the plaid sandbox while trying to create a bank account token **

- here i'm not connected stripe account with the plaid in plaid dashboard coz it's asking for live credentials
- i need to test both from the test account

```
    const request: ProcessorStripeBankAccountTokenCreateRequest = {
      access_token: plaidUser.accessToken,
      account_id:creditCardAccountId.account_id,
    };


    // Generate a bank account token
    const stripeTokenResponse = await plaidClient.processorStripeBankAccountTokenCreate(request);
```

// output

```
data: {
      display_message: null,
      documentation_url: 'https://plaid.com/docs/?ref=error#invalid-input-errors',
      error_code: 'INVALID_PRODUCT',
      error_message: 'the provided API keys are not enabled for the Stripe integration. please see https://plaid.com/docs/stripe/ for more information',
      error_type: 'INVALID_INPUT',
      request_id: 'A4YuCYqgnLLW3fz',
      suggested_action: null
    }
  },
```

expecting output like this

```
{
  "stripe_bank_account_token": "btok_5oEetfLzPklE1fwJZ7SG",
  "request_id": "[Unique request ID]"
}
```

Comment: If you want to use Stripe API for ACH Debit I invite you to refer to this:
https://stripe.com/docs/payments/ach-debit/accept-a-payment

Comment: thanks for answering my question but ACH is not the case, i'm facing issue with the plaid integration with stripe coz I don't stripe live account details as of now but is there any other way to test (plaid+ stripe) without the stripe live account credentials

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect your Stripe developer account to your Plaid developer account here

https://dashboard.plaid.com/developers/integrations

I'm not sure what you mean about not connecting because it asks for live credentials. You will be asked for your Stripe developer account credentials. Stripe does not have separate test and live developer accounts. You need both a valid Stripe developer account and a valid Plaid developer account to use the Stripe/Plaid integration.

Comment: without live credentials is there any other way to generate processorStripeBankAccountTokenCreate

Comment: any suggestions??